# ORACLE Managing Locked Accounts

Tags: sql, oracle

OK I'm currently doing a course in Oracle and I got this question as part of a project. I just was to know what system table can I query to get the following information.

> The utility should be able to identify each locked 
>   account that was locked because of invalid login attempts. 
>   The utility should further 
>   unlock accounts that have been locked for more than a week.

I know DBA_USERS shows all locked accounts but it does show why the account were locked. So  I can't use it to identify  if there are locked be case of invalid login attempts.

also I already know how to unlock them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the column: ACCOUNT_STATUS (in DBA_USERS).
Surprisingly - the information of the reason for the lock is there...

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_5081.htm#REFRN23302